# Trying to change IntegerProperty to FloatProperty of existing AppEngine DataStore. Getting error Indexed value must be at most 1500 bytes

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

BEFORE :

```
class Person(ndb.Model):

    name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    age = ndb.StringProperty()
    other_details = ndb.StructuredProperty(OtherDetails, 'othrdtl')

class OtherDetails(ndb.Model):

    success = ndb.StringProperty()
    qr_code = ndb.TextProperty()
```

AFTER:

```
class Person(ndb.Expando):
    pass
rows_to_be_updated = []
for person in Person.all():
    person.age = int(person.age)
    rows_to_be_updated.append(person)

if len(rows_to_be_updated)>0:
    ndb.put_multi_async(rows_to_be_updated)
```

#"When the above line is executed i am getting error"

Very AFTER:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    age = db.IntegerProperty()
    other_details = ndb.StructuredProperty(OtherDetails, 'othrdtl')
```

As per the datastore document, the TextProperty is unindexed by default. What is the reason for the error? I have tried making explicit Indexed=False (ndb.TextProperty(indexed= False)) but didn't work.

Comment: Without the full error message it's difficult to guess what your problem is.

Comment: suspended generator put(context.py:826) raised BadRequestError(The value of property "Person. qr_code" is longer than 1500 bytes.)

Comment: It seems that without the explicit definition as a text property on the write, the Expando isn't treating the read value as Text, but as a String.  Instead of making your Expando version empty, try defining all the fields other than age.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to go through an expando model, you might consider using a [different name](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) in your database than in your model.

E.g. after

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    string_age = ndb.StringProperty('age')
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty('int_age')
    other_details = ndb.StructuredProperty(OtherDetails, 'othrdtl')
```

Then you could use a [hook](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#hooks) to ensure that Person.age is always set, e.g.

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
  @classmethod
  def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
    p = future.get_result()
    if p and not p.age:
      p.age = int(p.string_age)
```